# How do I overwrite the form-control class in Bootstrap 3 with a custom class?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to override the width in the form-control class of Bootstrap 3.

Snippet:

```
<div class="col-xs-2">
         <label for="input-lastname" class="">Last Name</label>
         <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control my-form-inline" id="input-lastname" value="<?php  echo isset($_GET['lastname']) ? $_GET['lastname'] : 'empty';  ?>">
</div>...
```

I have this:

```
.form-control {
    min-width: 0;
    width: 25px;
    color:red;
}
```

`width` never works but the `color:red` does.  Using the developer tools in Chrome, I see where `.form-control` `.form-inline` have `width:auto`.  As soon as I uncheck `width` in those classes, I get my custom class.

I have my custom css as the last file loaded, so the order should be right.

I have tried:

```
.form-control, .my-form-inline {
    min-width: 0;
    width: 25px;
    color:red;
}

.form-control {
    min-width: 0;
    width: 25px;
    color:red;
}

.form-control, .form-inline, .my-form-inline{
    min-width: 0;
    width: 25px;
    color:red;
}
```

I seem to be able to override everything but the width.  My form's class is `form-inline`.

I have tried putting the form controls in a div with `col-md-2` (and xs), but it only seems to affect the label, not the input.  I can never override the `width:auto` unless I do it inline on the control in the HTML.  Removing the `form-control` class also allows me, as expected, to get my custom class.

EDIT:  For whatever reason, the forms.less mixin is winning over the style I load last.

EDIT:  The problem has to do with my specificity vs. Bootstrap's.  I have this inline in the  header:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {

    .form-inline .form-control {
      display: inline-block;
      width: auto;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .my-form-inline
    {
        min-width: 0;
        width: 25px;
        color:red;
    }
}
```

But the width is still overridden by some specificity I cannot find.

Comment: Your code works fine http://www.bootply.com/FKR6JrpWJj _assuming_ you are loading your CSS after the Bootstrap CSS

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn I have verified my custom css loads last in Chrome.  It shows it under everything else but Bootstrap is overriding everything.  I have to be missing the load sequence somewhere.  Edit:  I have also loaded it with <style> and it still does not beat out Bootstrap.

Comment: Chrome would show your styles _above_the others in the element inspector if they were loaded after

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn It doesn't.  I have to figure out why.

Answer (score 14):

Try to add `!important` after `width property value` as:

```
.form-control {
    min-width: 0;
    width: 25px !important;
    color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I was finally able to figure this out.  My level of specificity was incorrect, and my reference was also wrong.  It should have been:

```
.form-inline .my-form-inline
{
    min-width: 0;
    width: 25px;
    color:red;
}
```

It did not need to be in the correct `@media` section.